# ftp_get() corrupt large file download

Tags: php, ftp, wamp, lamp, gzip

I have to download a large file(approx~-9mb) in .gz format from the server using ftp. I have written a function which downloads the file completely and correctly but when i put this code online , the file is downloaded but the file gets corrupt. 
Here is my code:

```
function downloadFile($ftp_server, $username, $password, $server_file, $local_file)
{

// download server file
    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $username, $password);
    ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);
    if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
        echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
        //   exit;

    } else {
        echo "Error downloading $server_file.";
    }

}
```

Here is how i call it

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$xmlFile = __DIR__ . "/monster.xml.gz";
$local_file = __DIR__ . "/monster.xml";
$ftp_server = "ftp.monster.com";
$server_file = "/US~Partner~Sample Feed.xml.gz";


downloadFile($ftp_server,$username,$password,$server_file,$xmlFile);
```

The file must be downloaded and the then I will convert it into XML for further processing.
Note: The file is downloading perfect on localhost , this problem occurs as we put it on live server.

Comment: Why would you download a compressed file in ASCII mode?

Comment: I used it because it contains text only . Please guide me weather I should download it in which mode.

Comment: Try changing `mode` on the `ftp_get()` from `FTP_ASCII` to `FTP_BINARY` It is a zipped file therefore even if the contents WERE only text they WILL NOT be only text in the .gz file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GZ file may not only have text in it . So you have to download it with binary mode so that anything containing in it could be download successfully

```
if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
    //   exit;

} else {
    echo "Error downloading $server_file.";
}
```